# Add Hover & Click handlers to Quill blots

Tags: quill

I've already added my own custom `HighlightBlot` to my Quill instance, but now I'd like to add event handlers for hovering and clicking on those blots, so that I can display tooltips with metadata above the highlighted text, and other fun stuff like that...

The `HighlightBlot` is an `Inline` that renders into HTML that looks like this:

```
foo <span class="highlight-ABCD1234">bar</span> baz
```

Before switching to Quill, I was just using jquery to attach the handlers, like this:

```
let $highlight = $("span.highlight-ABCD1234")
$highlight.hover(onHighlightHover, onHighlightUnHover);
$highlight.click(onHighlightClick);
```

But I don't feel comfortable doing that now, since Quill takes complete ownership of the editor DOM, and I don't want to do any direct DOM manipulation myself that might interfere. Even if I *did* continue using jquery to attach handlers, I'm not quite sure where in the Quill rendering lifecycle I would put the handler-attachment code.

What should I do? Does quill have a mechanism for this?

Comment: You can attach listeners safely -- just don't cancel their effects so Quill gets them too. In general it's fine to use DOM APIs for read purposes but not write. For click you can use event delegation and attach to a DOM element above Quill's contents if you'd like.

As for where, you can either put it in the blot's static create method or the constructor.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!!